# Disable Active Indicator in Bottom Navigation Bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, navbar, bottomnavigationview

Basically what it says in the title. I have a Bottom Nav Bar in my Android Studio Project and want to disable the active indicator from my Bottom Navigation Bar.

Is there a simple way to just disable it? Or at least a workaround?

Currently, my code for the navbar looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navbar_fade"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/icon_color_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/icon_color_selector"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyleActive"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyleInactive"
    app:itemIconSize="40dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

For the navbar, I use this google library:

```
'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
```

Comment: There are several implementations of the bottom nav bar UI pattern. I recommend that you edit your question to explain which one you are using, such as via a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Use this to disable the Active indicator.

```
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
```

To change the Ripple color when you click on an item, use this.

```
app:itemRippleColor="@color/your_color"
```